# Google login / Third party authentication provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-signin

I'm developing an angularjs app where Google login is one of it's features. 
I'm using this link to implement the feature
 https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/06/angularjs-google-sign-integration/.
Here is also the script called when the page is loaded 
`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var p = document.createElement('script');
        p.type = 'text/javascript';
        p.async = true;
        p.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback';
        var  s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(p, s);
    })();
</script>
```

`

Is this the right way and how I can fetch data from google and show the data to the user and if he is happy to press sign up and then to be signed. I already have my app created into the google api service and tried many options but no success so far.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: check my answer ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initiate Google sign in on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624007/initiate-google-sign-in-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1):

Well this has a problem you would be login in directly with out being clicked so that might be a problem in future 
Try something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
       var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
       po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onLoadCallback';
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
     })();
</script>
```

In the view

```
function login() 
{
  var myParams = {
    'clientid' : 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com', //You need to set client id
    'cookiepolicy' : 'single_host_origin',
    'callback' : 'loginCallback', //callback function
    'approvalprompt':'force',
    'scope' : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read'
  };
  gapi.auth.signIn(myParams);
}
```

Convert this codes to Angular .

Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624007/initiate-google-sign-in-on-button-click) for details

Comment: Can you also post the onLoadCallBack function and tell me did i need it in my app.js file because since I created id there i got an error and my app stopped working. Here is my app.js.

Comment: `(function() {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("WebApp",
    [
        "something"
    ]);
    app.config([
            "$something",
            function ($something) {

                }
    ]);

    
    app.run([
            "$something",
            function ($something) {

                }
    ]);
    
}());

function onLoadFunction() {
   gapi.client.setApiKey('MyApiKey');
   gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {

   });
}();`